There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404) en Spring Boot
He estado practicando Java y Spring Boot para desarrollar una aplicación web. Sin embargo, me he encontrado con un problema relacionado con las rutas. Después de horas tratando de resolverlo, sigo sin éxito. Cuando intento acceder a cualquier ruta, obtengo el siguiente error:
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

A pesar de que ya definí las rutas en mi controlador (UsersController), sigo obteniendo este error.
A continuación, adjunto los archivos relevantes:
@Controller
public class HomeControllers {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository; // Repositorio de usuarios para acceder a la base de datos

    private static final String appName = "ThymeleafTour"; 
   
    @GetMapping("/Thymeleaf")
    public String home(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "Guest") String name) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("title", appName);
        return "home";
        }
    
    // Controlador para la página de lista de usuarios
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String users(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("usuarios", userRepository.findAll()); // Agrega todos los usuarios al modelo
        return "users"; // Devuelve el nombre de la plantilla Thymeleaf para la lista de usuarios
    }

    // Controlador para la página de agregar usuario
    @GetMapping("/agregar")
    public String agregar(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("usuario", new User()); // Agrega un nuevo usuario al modelo
        return "agregar"; 
    }

    // Controlador para procesar el formulario de agregar usuario
    @PostMapping("/agregar")
    public String agregarUsuario(@RequestParam("nombre") String nombre,
                                 @RequestParam("edad") Integer edad,
                                 @RequestParam("correo") String correo,
                                 RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        userRepository.save(new User(nombre, edad, correo)); // Guarda un nuevo usuario en la base de datos
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "El usuario a sido agregado correctamente"); // Agrega un mensaje de éxito para mostrar en la próxima página
        return "redirect:/users"; // Redirige a la página de lista de usuarios
    }

    // Controlador para procesar la eliminación de un usuario
    @PostMapping("/eliminar")
    public String eliminarUsuario(@RequestParam("nombre") String nombre, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        User user = userRepository.findByNombre(nombre); // Busca un usuario por su nombre
        if (user != null) {
            userRepository.delete(user);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "El usuario a sido eliminado correctamente"); 
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "Usuario no encontrado"); 
        }
        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    // Controlador para la página de edición de usuario
    @GetMapping("/editar")
    public String editar(@RequestParam("nombre") String nombre, Model model) {
        User usuario = userRepository.findByNombre(nombre); 
        if (usuario != null) {
            model.addAttribute("usuario", usuario); // Agrega el usuario al modelo
        }
        return "editar"; 
        
    }

    // Controlador para procesar la actualización de un usuario
    @PostMapping("/actualizar")
    public String actualizar(@RequestParam("nombreOriginal") String nombreOriginal,
                             @RequestParam("nombre") String nombre,
                             @RequestParam("edad") Integer edad,
                             @RequestParam("correo") String correo,
                             RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        User usuarioActualizar = userRepository.findByNombre(nombreOriginal); // Busca un usuario por su nombre original
        if (usuarioActualizar != null) {
            
            // Actualiza los datos del usuario
            usuarioActualizar.setNombre(nombre);
            usuarioActualizar.setEdad(edad);
            usuarioActualizar.setCorreo(correo);
            userRepository.save(usuarioActualizar); // Guarda los cambios en la base de datos
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "El usuario a sido actualizado correctamente"); 
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "No se encontró el usuario a actualizar"); 
        }
        return "redirect:/users"; 
    }
}

aqui mi reposirorio:
package com.example.application.repository;

import com.example.application.domain.User;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByNombre(String nombre);
    User findByCorreo(String correo);
}

el metodo main:
package com.example.application.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }

}

y mi pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.hutchinsonports.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

no se si sea relevante pero tambien adjunto la organizacion de archivos:

Podrías por favor ayudarme a entender qué está causando este error y cómo puedo solucionarlo? ¡Gracias!

spring boot soporta @RestController desde hace mucho deberías intentarlo

Posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/621506/no-puedo-cargar-mi-aplicaci%c3%b3n-de-spring-boot-en-la-web

En la captura de pantalla de tus ficheros aparece marcado el pom.xml con errores. Deberías corregir eso.

Si añades la siguiente dependencia a tu pom.xml (una vez arregles el error que aparece en la captura)
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

te saldrá más información cuando intentes acceder a un recurso que no existe [error 404]
Pantalla de error sin la dependencia spring-boot-devtools

Pantalla de error con la dependencia spring-boot-devtools

También sería interesante que indicaras cuál es la URL que estás intentando acceder. Dependiendo de si has definido la propiedad server.servlet.contextPath o no en tu fichero application.properties
spring.application.name=ThymeleafDemo
server.servlet.contextPath=/ThymeleafDemo

Si no la tienes definida, entiendo que estás accediendo a
http://localhost:8080

En caso de tenerla definida será
http://localhost:8080/ThymeleafDemo

